# forward logs every 30 min by logstash forwarder

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

is it possible to forward logs by logstash forwarder every 30 minute ?

can I use stop or start service every 30 min ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could have a cronjob that starts and stops logstash-forwarder at whatever interval you choose. Things to consider:

- There's no simple way to know when the current backlog has been processed, so if you don't let it run long enough each time you might be building up an ever-increasing backlog of messages.
- Make sure the filename patterns cover rotated files too so that you don't lose the last messages when files are rotated.